# Getting elements inside of elements using Cheerio

Tags: javascript, html, cheerio

Let's say I have some HTML like this:

```
<body>
 <a href="link A">Hello</a>
 <div class="main">
  <a href="link A">Hello</a>
 </div>
<body>
```

I want to use Cheerio to get the links that are only contained inside the div with the class main. How would I even start to go about doing this?

So far all I can even guess is doing something like:

```
$ = cheerio.load(body);
content = $('div.main');
```

But this obviously doesn't work because it never even tries to access any 'a' element inside of content (this is mostly because I have no clue how).

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `div.main a`?

Comment: or content.find('a')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a query selector, use `div.main a`:

```
content = $("div.main a");
```